# Like Facebook Page from Ionic 2 App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm developing a cross-platform App with Ionic 2 (angular2 & typescript).

I'm using the Ionic Native plugin to Login with facebook, but this plugin does not provide any way to Like Pages from my App.

I tried with the [Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) which is able to like pages but I don't get any response/callback from this action and I need to know when a user liked a page. This should work with any Facebook Page.

Any way to make this work? Preferably using the graph API.

Comment: why do you need to know if the user liked the page? what is the exact use case?

Comment: We want to reward the user for liking the page.

Comment: that is why i asked - you are not allowed to reward users for liking a page (it´s called "incentivizing"). you must read the platform policy before creating any app.